# Rails + Bind Model to jQuery Mobile Component in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile web app using Rails and jQuery Mobile. I've got a rails model called 'Event' and the corresponding controller and view (generated via scafolding). Now I'm working on the creation of a new Event using a form that has been generated. I'd like to slightly change this form but still be compatible with the rails model.

Here's how it looks now:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>      
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :priority %><br />
        <%= f.number_field :priority %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

The scafolded view is using some kind of default helper class I guess. But I'd like to change the f.number_field to a jQuery mobile slider which looks like this in html:

```
<label for="slider-1">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
```

Now, how do I combine the rails model with the jQuery slider, so that when the user clicks submit the clips_controller receives a clip model which contains the priority which has been adjusted using the slider?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [range_field](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/range_field) helper method

Instead of this:

```
<%= f.number_field :priority %>
```

Use this:

```
<%= f.range_field :priority, :min => 0, :max => 100 %>
```

Comment: it works. does this mean that every available helper method is compatible with jQuery Mobile? Even the parameter that custom jQuery components support/require? Thanks!

Comment: probably yes! please check the right side of the linked page to get available methods